# Kirby's theorem for 4-manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, knot-theory, surgery-theory, kirby-calculus

In dimension 3, we have the celebrated Kirby theorem: Let $L_1, L_2$ be two links in the 3-sphere $S^3$; then they surgeries along them produce homeomorphic 3-manifolds **if and only if** they are related by blow-ups and blow-downs.

I wonder if such wonderful theorem has a **4-dimensional generalization**. We do have basic moves for the Kirby diagrams from handle slidings and cancellations, but do they form a complete set of moves that characterize smooth 4-manifolds?

If such question is too hard, what can we say about for the more restricted cases (e.g. connected smooth closed oriented 4-manifold, whose Kirby diagram can be made simpler)?

#### Related

1. [What are Kirby diagrams of candidate exotic 4-manifolds?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155611/what-are-kirby-diagrams-of-candidate-exotic-4-manifolds)
2. [Given a Kirby diagram of a 4-manifold, what's its homotopy 2-type?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261770/given-a-kirby-diagram-of-a-4-manifold-whats-its-homotopy-2-type)
3. [Can cobordisms of 3 or 4 manifolds be visualized by moves on kirby diagrams?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285600/can-cobordisms-of-3-or-4-manifolds-be-visualized-by-moves-on-kirby-diagrams)

Comment: Yes, Cerf's theorem holds in all dimensions (even relative to a boundary) and is stated as 4.2.12 in the book by Gompf and Stipsicz. I think it is time to read that book :)

Comment: However, Cerf's result is not a generalization of Kirby's theorem.

Comment: @mme Thanks! For some reason I had the impression that the claim is wrong, so I kept searching such result from chapter 5 and after. I still wonder why dimension 4's result is much simpler than dimension 3, in which we need blowups.. Also, if these are exactly what we need, why is it hard to tell if two homeomorphic 4-manifolds are diffeomorphic or not?

Comment: It may help to bear in mind that there is no algorithm to tell if two smooth closed 4-manifolds are diffeomorphic.  Also, Kirby's theorem is a uniqueness result for a completely different sort of manifold description.  Namely, it describes when two Dehn surgery descriptions are the same - these are not the same as handlebody decompositions.

Comment: @Student: Just because you have a set of moves that connect two objects if they happen to be isomorphic does **not** mean you have an algorithm to decide if those objects are isomorphic.  For this, you would need an a priori bound on how many moves are needed.  So e.g. Kirby's theorem about 3-manifolds does not give you an algorithm to tell if two 3-manifolds are homeomorphic.  It gives you an algorithm that will eventually terminate of they are homeomorphic (ie enumerate all possible Kirby moves), but will run forever if they are not.

Comment: (it is true that there is such an algorithm for 3-manifolds, but it is far more complicated.  in other contexts, there might not be an algorithm at all.  e.g. it is known that if two group presentations define the same group, then they can be connected by a sequence of Tietze transformations [in fact, this is almost trivial]; however, it is also known that there is no algorithm to decide if two group presentations define the same group.)

Comment: There is an analogous theorem, but it has a fairly different shape.  Kirby's theorem for 3-manifolds is a manifestation of the fact that every 3-manifold is the boundary of a 4-manifold.  But not every 4-manifold is the boundary of a 5-manifold.  So the analogue for 4-manifolds will take its starting point not an empty link diagram, but a product of generators of the 4-dimensional oriented cobordism group.  The generator being $\mathbb CP^2$.   From this connect sum you would have a surgery diagram, but again you may have surguries of different-dimensional objects.

Comment: Cerf theory sounds more powerful than I expect! Thank you all!

Comment: @RyanBudney Do you happen to know a similar statement for the piecewise-linear setup? In dimension 4 and 5, it's known that PL is smooth. But I wonder if the same thing holds for PL in all dimensions. Standard textbook like Rourke&Sanderson doesn't seem to contain such statement.. perhaps we need a PL Cerf theory?